# show a modal pop up for 10 seconds or until a flag or variable is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am a beginner in jquery so pardon for the mistakes. I want to show a modal pop up for 10 seconds or until a flag or variable is set, then hide this modal pop up and then open another one depending on the flag or variable. Here is the code that I have done so far,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnopen").click(function() {
    $('#myModal1').modal('show');

    setTimeout($('#myModal1').modal('hide'), 10000);  //show myModal1 for 10 seconds
  if({{ flag }}){
    $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
   $('#myModal2').modal('show');  //If flag is set close myModal1 and open myModal2
}
else{
      $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
    $('#myModal3').modal('show');  //else close myModal1 and open myModal3
}
});
$("#btnClose1").click(function() {
  $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
});
$("#btnClose2").click(function() {
  $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
});
$("#btnClose3").click(function() {
  $('#myModal3').modal('hide');
});});
```

The issue now I am facing is I cannot show myModal1 for 10 seconds. I have searched some documents but nothing solved my problem. Can anyone help me?.
**Edit**
What should I do if I want the myModal1 pop up close only after the flag is set else, after 30 seconds close myModal1 pop up and open myModal3 pop up.              Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use setTimeout as `setTimeout(function(){ $('#myModal1').modal('hide'), 10000);`

Comment: @PPL Thank you for your answer. I changed the line but same result. myModal1 opened and closed within a second and then opened myModal3. I think the problem is with the flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code, this may help you

```
var myVar;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#btnopen").click(function () {
        $('#myModal1').modal('show');

        myVar=setTimeout(function(){
    $('#myModal1').modal('hide');

    if (flag){
        $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
        $('#myModal2').modal('show');  //If flag is set close myModal1 and open myModal2
      }
    else{
        $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
        $('#myModal3').modal('show');  //else close myModal1 and open myModal3
      }
        }, 10000);  //show myModal1 for 10 seconds

    });


    $("#btnClose1").click(function () {
      $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
clearTimeout(myVar);
    });
    $("#btnClose2").click(function () {
      $('#myModal2').modal('hide');
clearTimeout(myVar);
    });
    $("#btnClose3").click(function () {
      $('#myModal3').modal('hide');
clearTimeout(myVar);
    });

    });
```

Do not put the following code just after setTimeout(function(){},10000);
because the following code will get execute just after setTimeout(function(){},10000); and will not wait for 10 sec. this is an async execution will callback after 10 sec

```
if({{ flag }}){
    $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
   $('#myModal2').modal('show');  //If flag is set close myModal1 and open myModal2
}
```

Comment: Thank you Faraz. One more help needed. Please find the edited question.

Comment: @Tony Joy on which button click you want to close  myModal1 popup?

Comment: If flag is set I want to close the myModal1 pop up and open myModal2 else show the myModal1 pop up for 10 seconds and after that close it and open myModal3 pop up..

Comment: Creat new myVar1=  setTimeout(function(){},1000) which after each second and check flag. if flag is set than clear both clearTimeout(myVar1); clearTimeout(myVar);

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for **[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)** is not correct. You will need to wrap your code into a function which will run after time expire.

***Note:*** I think you are getting the value of `flag`...I have taken the flag value 1 for now

```js
var flag = 1;
$("#btnopen").click(function() {
  $('#myModal1').modal('show');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
    if (flag) {
      $('#myModal2').modal('show');
    } else {
      $('#myModal3').modal('show')
    }
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnopen">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal2</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal3</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Bhuwan for your answer. I changed the line but same result. myModal1 opened and closed within a second and then opened myModal3. I think the problem is with the flag.

Comment: @TonyJoy what is flag here..?

Comment: I am using flask framework. So I am sending flag from the backend function to html file. Actually the code is for a device discovery. If the device is discovered this flag is set.

Comment: @TonyJoy it means you are getting the value of flag...right...?

Comment: Yes. Flag is a boolean value.

Comment: @TonyJoy so if flag is true, you want to show modal2 else modal3...right..? also you want this to execute when modal1 is close..?

Comment: Thank you. This works fine when I try to run here. But at my end it is not working.